# How can I apply transform on a linked object via Python?

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, linked-data

I have myself a linked object in my scene. I can't move it manually, but I can change it's location with Python. However I also want to apply the transform. I tried it using ob.transform_apply (loc=True etc.), but the script then failed. I tried it with a different, unlinked object and it worked. Is there a way to apply transform on a linked object too?